# Why do we need to have a reference temperature to define thermal coefficient of resistance (TCR)

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance

Why do we need to have a reference temperature to define thermal coefficient of resistance (TCR)?

TCR is the change in resistance per change in temperature divided by the resistance at a specified, fixed reference temperature:

Comment: Because it varies with temperature, so you need to know if you are close to where the value is quoted or you have to find a better value for your temperature of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal coefficient of resistance is the derivative of resistance with respect to temperature or $\alpha=\frac{dR}{dT}$.

However this coefficient changes with temperature! So obviously you can only give the coefficient at a given temperature,  unless the resistance is perfectly linear in T for all temperatures (no material has such a property). In other words,  $\alpha$ is itself a function of $T$.

Comment: This wiki article gives a different definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_coefficient as does the OP in his question